# How to show the unicode in cakephp when using SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

I use the cakephp with SQL server 2012. In my database I have declare nvarchar instead of varchar to show the unicode. But when I use

```
$this->set('types',$this->Manager->query('select * from product_types'))
```

the result is :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Th?c u?ng c� c?n
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => B�nh k?o
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => X� b�ng
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => H�ng h�a d�ng h?p
                )

        )

)
```

It doesn't show unicode characters.

Comment: is characters ok, directly at the db?

Comment: it is ok, when i use sql managerment studio 2012 to query !!!

Comment: do you have meta tag like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8 ">` ?

Comment: Yes, i already have inserted it on my meta tag ?? plz i can not find what happen ??

Answer (score 1):

You should change your database setting in app/Config/database.php:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

to:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8', //uncomment this line
);
```